# React: render Html tags into formatted text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying the data that is coming from webapi response. Sometimes it's having HTML content. I need to render HTML tags into formatted text.
I am using {ReactHtmlParser(item.value)}. It's not converting the below tags. Please help.

```
&nbsp;<span style="color:#666666; font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-size:12pt"><strong>Other documents</strong></span>

 <p>Discontinued</p>
```

Thanks

Comment: could you also show us a sample API data which are you getting from the API response.

Comment: Maybe you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` instead? https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Comment: Could it be the double quotes around the style property? This seems to work fine (with single quotes): https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-black-orjuxs

Comment: data is coming from database, its having html content

Comment: Api returns this kind of data: <Category>
<description description-id="1">&amp;nbsp;&lt;span style="color:#666666; font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-size:12pt"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Other&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</description>

<description description-id="1544">Product Guide</description>
<description description-id="1535">&lt;p&gt;Discontinued&lt;/p&gt;</description>

</Category>